# How can I set the location for the cobertura data file when using the cobertura maven plugin?

Tags: maven, cobertura

I am using cobertura maven plugin 2.4. I don't see any option to set the location to store the datafile (cobertura.ser) to a particular folder.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOBERTURA-57

> Arnaud Heritier added a comment - 09/Dec/07 4:16 PM
>
> Fixed with cobertura 1.9
>   By default the cobertura.ser file is now in:
>   `${project.build.directory}/cobertura/cobertura.ser`
>
> It can be changed in the plugin config with:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <dataFile>${basedir}/target/test-harness/check/cobertura.ser</dataFile>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: When I try this I get "Cannot override read-only parameter: dataFile in goal: cobertura:instrument"

Comment: does not work for me. setting `dataFile` has no effect with cobertura maven plugin v2.5.2

Answer (score 1):

From the [Cobertura FAQ](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/faq.html), you could use the property `net.sourceforge.cobertura.datafile`.

For instance`-Dnet.sourceforge.cobertura.datafile=${basedir}/cobertura.ser`

Comment: Thanks but net.sourceforge.cobertura.datafile just tell you where the datafile is.